# Is "data" treated as singular or plural in formal contexts?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, formality, latin, uncountable-nouns

My non-native English speaking friend just asked me: "Data *is*..." or "Data *are*..."?

I said *both* but that's because I've been desensitized from reading/writing both (especially from writing code and adding quick comments).

**My question**: Is it acceptable to utilize either for a **university paper**? Or is one *safer* than the other (when confronted with stickler professors)?

---

Related questions:

- [Is the word "data" now considered singular? If so, what about "datum"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/is-the-word-data-now-considered-singular-or-still-plural)
- [Data is/are in a global context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81707/data-is-are-in-a-global-context)

Comment: Just out of interest, is it now considered acceptable to utilize "utilize" instead of using "use" as in the question above? Or should I stop worrying about this?

Comment: You should ask this as a question (i.e. not just me) - I'm a bit curious now too! Personally I just always assumed it to be a synonym of _use_.

Comment: done! http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7017/has-utilise-lost-its-meaning-in-america

Comment: tchrist's answer to [this subsequent question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81707/data-is-are-in-a-global-context) is also of great interest.

Comment: Permit me to kindly offer [this brief but data-driven response](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/82773).

Comment: It is a ["deep philosophical question"](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1816).

Comment: If you don't have myriad uses of the word in your paper, you could simply avoid the conundrum by using constructions like "Our data *points* suggest that" or "the data we gathered" that work either way.

Comment: This issue being quite well known, the answer surely is 'consult the institution's style guide'.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I have actually considered this quite a bit, being both a linguist who studies these things, and a scholar who publishes papers.

Etymologically speaking, the word *data* is the plural of *datum* in Latin.  In Latin, *data* would get plural verb agreement.  Now, languages borrow words and do whatever they want with them, so this historical fact about *data* has no relevance in judging what is "correct" in English.  There is significant evidence that *data* has established itself as a mass noun in English, suggesting that, for most people, "data is" is the most natural way to speak.

**However**, in a university/scholarly paper, I would recommend using "data are", rather than "data is".

The reason: some stickler professors and pedantic scholars believe that, logically, if *datum* is an English word for a single piece of *data* (which it is), that *data* **must** logically be plural.  The fact that most people do things differently only means, to them, that most people are doing it wrong.  Whether you agree with that or not is somewhat irrelevant.

So you have two choices.

1. If you use "data is", then reasonable people (yes, I am biased) who read your paper will not bat an eye, but stickler professors might judge you on your perceived ignorance or inappropriate level of informality.
2. If you use "data are", then the stickler professors will not judge you to be ignorant, and the reasonable people will think "that's an acceptable variant" or "this person is a stickler for language" (or if they are me, will think "this person is pandering to the sticklers — a necessary evil"), but nobody will think you are ignorant.

So, choosing (2), "data are" is clearly your safest bet, and is what I always do (and what I find nearly all of my colleagues do).

Comment: +1 A good answer, though I would say it depends what you study and the English ability of said professors.  Where I studied, a major international university, many of the professors did not have English as a first language and would be more likely to know and accept the colloquial use.  Indeed, most of my professors were not red hot in English, as is common in Computing.

Comment: @Orbling: I can't say this for certain about every person, but I imagine non-native speakers would accept this use from a native speaker, even if they would not be familiar with it.  (At the same time, if they have been reading academic papers for years, they might well *be* familiar with it anyway.)

Comment: True, it certainly depends upon the individual person.  When I hear *"data are"* it grates, no matter how many times I have seen it in research papers.

Comment: I'm a scholar of sorts, and write and say *"data are"* in academic contexts. Usually: sometimes I forget. That said, I would never correct someone who sad *"data is"* nor hold it against them. That usage is fixed now, and I suppose the formally correct usage will die in time.

Comment: Even though this rule happens to be somewhat stricter in Dutch, it is a well-know mistake, even condoned by some; so Dutch readers would usually not be shocked to see it in another language, concluding that, apparently, "they made a different choice", that it is probably acceptable in that language. But if they have seen *both* variants in English, they might conclude that "some people got their etymology together and others don't" — or they might not notice. It could go either way.

Comment: One way to "soften" the "grating effect" is to add a couple of words between data and the plural verb.  For example, instead of "Our data suggest that..." one could write "The data we collected suggest that..."  (Normally, I recommend striking superfluous words, rather than adding them, but this might be one exception – assuming the author felt in a quandary about which to use).

Comment: data is more naturally used with "is". It's usage is similar to quantities like "sugar". We say "there is sugar in the recipe" instead of "there are sugar(s) in the recipe". Data is an indeterminate specifier of one or more datum. There is never a need to be term specific with data. The only case where one and only one data element is being specified, it is a datum.

Comment: You do not have to know any English to know that data is the plural of datum.

Comment: While the colloquial form feels natural and would work in most circumstances, here are circumstances when, even in colloquial usage, *are* makes more sense.  *The data are contradictory*. We are almost certainly talking about separate data sets, and the plural emphasizes that.

Comment: @bib That actually seems like an argument for the colloquial. If you use the formal consistently, "the data are contradictory" is ambiguous, meaning it could refer to 2 data sets that aren't in agreement or one data set that doesn't agree with itself (meaning its validity should be questioned). If using the mass noun in other places, this distinction is more obvious when you later use "data are".

Comment: @Orbling: Certainly the professors still have a more than adequate command of English if they use English all day long. Their accents might be a bit non-native but their understanding of the language is still largely better than many would suppose.

Comment: In a university setting, one would expect a stipulative decree on such issues in the in-house style guide.

Comment: Anyone who says/writes 'the data are' must also say or write things like "the data were wrong".  It will make you sound super smart.

Answer (score 17):

This is intended as a clarification of the "correctness" of using data as a mass noun, for those strict-minded sticklers (there's plenty of them) who might be unconvinced by Kosmonaut's "languages borrow words and do whatever they want with them":

> 1 - "Datum" and "data (plural)" are historically correct, so "data (mass noun)" must be wrong. How can "data" have a mass noun form as well as a singular and plural?
>   You'd never say "Oh, I spilled rice on the floor. Wait, it's okay, I only
>   spilled 4 rices". There's a separate noun phrase for the singular and
>   plural ("grains of rice").

Consider *potato*. It has a singular form, meaning one distinct root vegetable, a plural form, meaning multiple distinct root vegetables, and a mass form, meaning an amount of foodstuff made from potatoes. Imagine a dinner table, where each diner has a baked potato on their plate (singular), and everyone is sharing a platter of roast potatoes (plural) and a bowl of mashed potato (mass) (hopefully among other things...). If you ask someone to "pass the potato", they'll understand that you mean the bowl of mass mash, not the tray of plural potatoes or the singular potato on their plate.

> 2 - There can be such a thing as "a datum" in a way which is not true
>   for "a water". Imagine someone looking at a database full of data and
>   saying, "There is so much data in this, I can't see where to start".
>   Surely this is like standing in a migration of birds and saying "There
>   is so much bird in the sky, I can't see the sun..."? Since data can be
>   countable, surely "data" can't be primarily a mass noun?

*Data* is not necessarily countable. Data in a neat Excel sheet might have countable cells, but what about the data that is lost when photo editors talk about "data loss" when increasing the contrast of a digital photo made of binary machine code data? There's no clear way of defining where one datum starts and the next one stops — would a datum in this context be a bit, a byte, or the data defining one pixel? Such a line would be arbitrary, like looking for units of rice in a processed flat rice cracker. It's an amount measured in units of mass — 67kb of data in a jpg, 2 grams of rice in a rice cracker.

Even seemingly trivial cases aren't so trivial. What's one datum in a modern relational database? One value, one row? What about where there are table joins and foreign keys? Is a structural definition a datum? You can create a convention-specific definition, but it's not a universal definition like one bird.

> 3 - Following that pattern, shouldn't the mass noun of data be datum
>   (the singular), like how the mass noun of potatoes is potato?

No. It's rare, but not completely unique, for a count noun to develop from a plural, in cases where the singular over time becomes less and less universally meaningful. "Physics" used to mean the set of countable, defined, distinct natural sciences - until the field developed such that it became clear that the lines between one physic and another wasn't as sharp or universal as previously thought.

You could answer "What's happening at CERN?" with "A lot of physics", but you wouldn't expect the reply "How many?". This is because there's no longer a clear established universal dividing line between one physic and another. Your answer would interpret the question as, "How much?" and would be a measurement of amount: "Enough to occupy 4,000 physicists". In the same way, you could answer "What does this supercomputer store?" with "A lot of data", but the reply "How many?" would incorrectly assume that all data has one clear common countable unit and that there is a clear universal dividing line between one datum and another across all contexts. Even if this data did happen to have a consistent countable convention, replying "7 million data" would be ambiguous unless the asker already knew this convention. A more useful answer would be to interpret it as "How much?" and give an answer in terms of a measurement of amount: "Nearly 220 petabytes".

Comment: I've only ever heard "mashed potatoes" referred to as plural (you never mash just one potato). Is this a regional difference (I'm from western Canada)?

Comment: @kappamaki, It seems that it's regional. Both sound natural to me.

Comment: It might also help to mention that other words taken from Latin have undergone the same change: *agenda* is plural in Latin, but has evolved to become singular in English. There are also words where this evolution happened before entering English, such as *joy* (from French *joie,* from the Latin plural *gaudia*).

Answer (score 15):

I'm a strong proponent of data as a mass noun, taking the singular in grammatical usage ("the data *shows* us something").  Use of *data* as a plural ("the data *show* us...") seems pretentious and pedantic, as if to make a show of your knowledge that in Latin, *data* is a plural form of *datum*.

I have several reasons for being stubborn about *data* as a mass noun:

1. *Datum* is a reference line in a mechanical drawing. More than one of these may be called *data*, if you must show off your knowledge of Latin, but I think in this case they'll usually be referred to as *datum lines*.
2. If you can tell me *how many data* you have, then I will use plural verbs to refer to your *data*, but as long as you need quantitative units to tell me the size of your data, then I will call it a collective singular:  *e.g.* "There *is* too much data to load into memory."  I can't imagine anyone being comfortable saying, "There are too *many* data to load."  Likewise, we say, "My hard drive holds up to 1 TB of data."  It's nonsensical to talk about there being "1 trillion data in there."
3. Even semantically, there is not an easy concept of singular data, as we currently use the term.  No data point can stand on its own, but rather it derives meaning and significance from its context.  What were the conditions of its measurement?  What were the other measurements?  Etc.  It doesn't make semantic sense to refer to a single datum unless it has that specific meaning, as a reference point or baseline.  What we mean by data as a plural is semantically different from what we mean by data as a collective singular.

Answer (score 6):

It's a great example of a **word in transition**.

"Traditionally" it was the plural form of **datum**.

The fact is though, more and more "authorities" are using it as a singular.

"The Oxford English Dictionary defines it like this:

In Latin, data is the plural of datum and, historically and in specialized scientific fields , it is also treated as a plural in English, taking a plural verb, as in *the data were collected and classified.* In modern non-scientific use, however , despite the complaints of traditionalists, it is often not treated as a plural. Instead, it is treated as a mass noun, similar to a word like *information*, which cannot normally have a plural and takes a singular verb. Sentences such as *data was* (as well as *data were*) *collected over a number of years* are now widely accepted in standard English."

In contrast to that:

"The official view from the Office for National Statistics takes the traditional approach. The ONS style guide for those writing official statistics says:

The word data is a plural noun so write "data are". Datum is the singular."

http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2010/jul/16/data-plural-singular

It's worth remembering the priceless words from an introduction to the OED: "This book is descriptive, not prescriptive."

Once again, "data" is a great example of a word in transition.  A reminder that with questions of spelling and grammar, the concept of what's "right" is a difficult one. All truth is social, and all the more so with language correctness.

[image]

Comment: But Data was a one-off.

Comment: To be sure to be sure, I included that picture just because it's such a fantastic picture - it wasn't evidential or exemplary!

Comment: And like I mentioned in a flag, I seriously think this should be reopened, since the picture and legend is so awesome.

Answer (score 3):

As addressed in the question linked, it depends if you use the uncountable noun, meaning "a collection of data", or the plural form of [*datum*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/datum). If it is the former, then the verb would be singular, otherwise it would be plural.

Now I would say, that in most **university papers**, you would use the uncountable singular form. The exception would be when data would describe an ensemble of measurements or when data is used in philosophy paper. (According to Wiktionary's definition.)

Comment: Just because a noun is uncountable doesn't mean that it has to be singular. Consider *clergy* and *gentry*. A collection of data is commonly called *a data set* in scientific writing. In modern usage, I would definitely classify the noun *data* as uncountable, independent of whether it is singular or plural.

Comment: @Peter: For me, the fact that when _data_ is plural, it is the plural form of _datum_, which seems to be a countable noun when looking at the definition, makes the _plural_ data countable. Note that I never say that all uncountable words were to be singular.

Comment: I thought you implied that all uncountable words were singular when you said that if *data* was not the plural of *datum,* it had to be singular.

Comment: 'Data' is a plural form no matter how you decide to use it in a sentence. When used in noncount usage, it is given a singular verb form; when used as a count usage (with rare singular 'datum') it takes a plural verb form. The count usage is rarely found outside academia.

Answer (score 2):

Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says:

> After data, you can use a singular verb or, in formal or technical English, a plural verb.
>
> Example:
> The data is collected by trained interviewers.
> These data are summarized in Table 5.

Do not say 'datas’ or 'a data'.

And based on Oxford:

> Data is used as a plural noun in English while the sigular is datum.

Answer (score 1):

AHDEL has, for **news**: **pl.n. (used with a sing. verb).**

Collins has **n (functioning as singular)**, not claiming it as a plural noun, though it gives both singular and plural near-synonyms in its definitions of polysemes:

1. current events; important or interesting recent happenings
2. information about such events, as in the mass media

Surely the way the noun is (in this case universally) used rather than its form (or its origin, from a plural noun in Middle English **newes**, meaning new things) decides correct usage. **Tidings** is treated differently.

However, **data** is treated as requiring singular concord by some authorities and plural concord by others - as stated in previous answers. (Amusingly, in this case Collins is slightly more prescriptive than the AHDEL!) I believe that normal non-academic usage strongly advocates singular concord, while different universities still hold different opinions. Because there are no ex-cathedra (in the absolute sense) rulings in these areas, a university must give its own preferences in an in-house style guide (as many do) and be prepared to tolerate opposing usages from other equally entitled institutions. Students should make sure that, in submitted work, they follow the style guide of the university that will ultimately pass or fail them.

Comment: It would be good to clarify that you mean "the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language."  "AHDEL" does not match that in top Google searches or Wikipedia disambiguation.

Comment: The people editing to expand 'AHDEL' to 'the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language'  probably haven't checked to see that 'AHD' is one of the abbreviations listed for use in answers in Meta. 'AHD' is the suggested form there, but the generally accepted form is 'AHDEL'. Googling "AHDEL acronym" will get a person swiftly to the expansion. I've 'de-edited' merely to make the point that if people are going to be prescriptivist, they should get their own rules right first. ELU allows common linguistic abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting this, I just answered a dupe of this, so here was my answer there:

Essentially, this comes down to "It's plural if you want it to be." I never liked that answer, either.

[However](http://www.onlinegrammar.com.au/top-10-grammar-myths-data-is-plural-so-must-take-a-plural-verb/), [people](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/data.html) [really](http://nxg.me.uk/note/2005/singular-data/) [like](http://www.gpuss.co.uk/english_usage/data_plural_singular.htm) [arguing](http://johnaugust.com/2004/data-is-singular) [about](http://grammarist.com/usage/data/) [this](http://afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/07/02/singular-plural-pick-one/?_r=0).

Etymologically, *data* comes from Latin. This is well-known. Unfortunately, in Latin, its plurality was defined by devices that exist in English only in a far lesser capacity: gender and noun case.

In the Latin nominative case, *data* could be either the neuter plural or the feminine singular of *datum*. The neuter singular was *datum*, the masculine singular *datus*, the feminine plural *datae*, and the masculine plural *dati*.

Use of *data* as a plural in English (the earlier form) comes from a suggestion that we should incorporate the words closest in Latin meaning to how they will be used in English: the neuter singular *datum* and the neuter plural *data*.

However, *data* could also function as the feminine singular in Latin, which I conjecture led to its commonplace use as a mass noun in English.

I enjoy using these words as they were used in Latin: in a survey of male students, I might say "After the dati were collected, each outlying datus was removed." In a survey of female students, I might say "After the datae were collected, each outlying data was removed." In a survey of pineapples, I might say "After the data were collected, each outlying datum was removed."

Most people do not enjoy this. The first two usages are not by any means commonplace (possibly even unattested outside random tangents on the internet), with the third occasionally seen as archaïc but often accepted or even preferred, with *data* used as plural.

It is more common today, however, to use *data* as a mass noun; that is, "the data was collected," not "each data was collected." *Datum* remains typical in the latter case.

Answer (score 1):

"a bowl of mashed potato"
This is very strange, at least in US useage. In my 67 years I don't think I have ever heard anyone say other than "a bowl of mashed potatoes," and I've lived from North Caroilina to Indiana to New York to Connecticut to Michigan to Louisiana and back to North Carolina by way of Tennessee. A mashed potato is possible, but only if one mashes but one potato.
Data works well as a mass/common noun with a singular verb as long as the data is of a uniform nature (concerning only per capita income). If the data is varied (concerning both per capita income and books purchased per unit of time), then it is not a mass/common noun and would do well to take a plural verb.
It would only seem reasonable to vary datum's declension according to sex if it were used as an adjective. In the examples above, it is a noun. In those examples, only the neuter datum/data, "a thing/the things given," would seem appropriate. In any case, one should note that the Latin 2nd declension masculine plural ending "i" was pronounced much as the English "ee," and the Latin 1st declension feminine plural "ae" was pronounced similar to the English "eye," which rather confuses both the point and any listeners who might care to understand why one would choose to say such things.

Comment: As a Brit, I can say both -- pass the potatoes, and pass the potato. Assuming a common bowl or plate. If they were baked, boiled or fried I should prefer the former, if mashed the latter, but would not be fazed by the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

As far as actual examples of use is concerned, the following is from the OED:

> **1. As a count noun: an item of information; a datum; a set of data.** *Also figurative.*
>
> 2006   Cancer Causes & Control 17 1055/2   *These **datas were** likely not missing at random.*
>
> **2. As a mass noun. a. Related items of (chiefly numerical) information considered collectively, typically obtained by scientific work and used for reference, analysis, or calculation.**
>
> 1983   J. C. Quicker Homegirls iii. 58   *This **data comes** from..numerous interviews with gang girls.*
>
> **b. Computing. Quantities, characters, or symbols on which operations are performed by a computer, considered collectively.** Also (in non-technical contexts): information in digital form. Cf. datum n. 1b.
>
> 1992   MacUser 21 Feb. 12 (advt.)    *Our hard disk has crashed and irreplaceable **data is** lost forever.*

Answer (score 0):

I would regard "the data is consistent" and "the data are consistent" as having slightly different meanings.  The former carries an implication that some particular (possibly large) set of information was *completely* examined and found to be consistent.  The latter carries an implication that multiple independent pieces of information were examined, but does not particularly imply that any particular identifiable set of information was examined completely.  Neither implication is absolute, in but some situations I would suggest the singular form as more appropriate, and in others I would suggest the plural.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [IEEE Style Guide](https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html) (archive link [here](http://web.archive.org/save/http://web.archive.org/web/20200107155207/https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/conferences/conference-template-letter.docx)), under "Some Common Mistakes":

> The word “data” is plural, not singular.

So if your formal context is an IEEE venue, the answer is authoritatively "plural."

Comment: The word _measles_ 'is plural', but is almost always afforded a singular verb-form. You need to give an example sentence from your source. / That said, IEEESG probably _does_ require 'data are', but we don't really want 100 non-consensual pronouncements from 100 different style guides.

Comment: Someone trying to write a formal paper for an IEEE venue might have this question: *Is “data” treated as singular or plural in formal contexts?* So they come here, and maybe search on page (CTRL+F) for "IEEE". Here's the authoritative answer.  I've avoided the strongly discouraged answering-in-comments-on-the-question strategy. The style guide has an authoritative sentence (quoted) but not example sentences; one might be "The data are from Johnson's 2019 experiments [1] and additionally show trufflets are negatively charged in 75% of observations."

Comment: In ELU Meta, under [Are questions about style guides appropriate?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), is the answer: "According to the closing of my question, it seems the Writers Stack Exchange is the proper place for questions about style guides and style usage. ... edited Apr 13 '17 at 12:40 Community♦  answered Jun 26 '11 at 13:27 Ricket". I'd go further, and say that ELU is not the place where questions/answers about style requirements of domain-specific authorities (law, science, technology etc) should be posted. They often cut across standard usages. As here.

Comment: This is not a question about a style guide.  This is an answer to a question that cites an appropriate authority, which will be the best answer for at least some subset of readers.  If you aren't in that subset and don't like it, there are plenty of other answers on this question that you might like better.  There are good reasons why SE allows for multiple answers to the same question!

Answer (score -1):

Technically plural; your instincts are correct. But colloquial usage probably allows for either at this late date in many dictionaries, I would guess.