# Has "utilise" lost its meaning in America?

Tags: word-choice, differences

My understanding is that "utilise" means to use an object for a task for which it was not intended.

However, in American English, it seems that "utilize" is synonymous with "use", and it seems that "utilize" is used to make a sentence sound more complex or formal.

Is this the accepted usage now? Is the benefit people find in making a sentence sound more complex overtaking the benefit of being able to express the different meanings?

Answer (score 13):

My Webster's says

> **utilize** |ˈyoōtlˌīz| verb [ trans. ]
> make practical and effective use of :
> vitamin C helps your body utilize the
> iron present in your diet.
>
> USAGE
> Utilize, borrowed in the 19th
> century from the French : utiliser,
> means 'make practical or effective use
> of.' Because it is a more formal word
> than **use** and is often used in contexts
> (as in business writing) where the
> ordinary verb **use** would be simpler and
> more direct, **utilize** may strike
> readers as pretentious jargon and
> should therefore be used sparingly.

I have never heard *utilize* to mean "use an object for a task for which it was not intended." Indeed, when I googled the British spelling, I got this:

> **utilise** - put into service; make work
> or employ for a particular purpose or
> *for its inherent or natural purpose*;

[Emphasis my own]

This directly contradicts your assertion of a contrary meaning for the word.

Comment: fair enough! Seems like I've got it the wrong way around!

Comment: I should have said I was getting my source from the wiktionary. Maybe it needs updating? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/utilize

Comment: Good ole Merriam Webster puts it much more simply 

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utilise

("British variant of utilize")

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to its cognate in French, *utilise* is in most senses identical to *use*.  The *-ise* suffix means it's a process (the process of gaining utility), and it's often used in business speak to suggest effective or deliberate use - think of it as "use to your profit".  It can also be used to avoid ambiguity or negative connotations (e.g. *utilising* rather than *using* a workforce).

It doesn't mean to use an object for a task for which it was not intended. For that, there are plenty of words, but I prefer to use *hack*.

Comment: *Jury-rig* is a much older term meaning the same thing.

Comment: Re “It doesn't mean ... not intended” note wiktionary's sense 4 of *[utilise](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/utilise#Verb)*:  “To make do with; to use in manner different from that originally intended”

Comment: yeah, it's easy to see how it can go from "use a weakness to profit" to "use in a manner other than intended". I think it was a bit strong to say "It doesn't mean..."

Answer (score 1):

I observe a slight difference between them, but not quite the distinction that you expect.

"I occasionally use the second bathroom in my house, but it will be utilized when my nephew moves in."

In that sense it means to give utility to something. This seems to match the idea of using something for an unintended purpose, but also matches the idea of beginning to use something for its intended purpose after it had not been used (to its fullest capacity) previously.

Comment: So when you use something, it might not have utility?

Answer (score 0):

They both came from Latin. In the etymological sense, to [use](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=use) has a broad meaning, while to utilise mean "to use something in order to obtain something else".

For example I utilise the bathroom (to ease myself) but I cannot utilise the sofa (i.e. using it resting upon it).