# With "amount" will you use singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

I am confused about this grammatical question:

- large amount of data and the fact that **it** will exponentially grow
- large amount of data and the fact that **they** will exponentially grow

(the semantic is that the number of data will increase).

Which of the two forms is the correct one?

Comment: I prefer *it*.  Referring to *amount* which is singular.

Comment: I second GEdgar. Singular.

Comment: I'd also prefer you to say, "..it will grow exponentially..." See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/is-data-considered-singular-or-plural

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

> ...large amount of data and the fact that X will exponentially grow

what is X referring to? 'Amount' or 'data'?

X refers to 'amount' and IT will grow. (if you take away the prepositional phrase, nothing else whould change, 'the amount, it will grow'.

See what happens with

> ...large amount of apples and the fact that X will exponentially grow

If you said 'they will grow', you'd presumably be referring to the individual apples, but instead you are talking about the -amount- that will grow.

This is confusing because both 'amount' is a mass noun and 'data' is naturally taken to be a mass noun but pedantically is considered the plural of a count noun (with the rare 'datum' as the singular).

Comment: This is at variance with OP's "number of data" rather than "amount of data". While your argument is perfect, it is not relevant the question.

Comment: @Kris If the Asker did not consider Mitch's Answer relevant, why did they accept it? It's my impression that the Question came from someone who speaks English as a second language. "number of data", I think they meant "quantity of data".

Comment: You do? I didn't, though.

Comment: @Kris: the wording the OP uses is 'amount of data' so that is what I responded to. Yes, he uses 'number' in the explanation, but the response is relevant to the phrasing as asked, 'it' or 'they'.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite for less awkwardness, e.g.

> The volume of data is already large and is set to grow exponentially.

Comment: see also: my comment at answer by Mitch.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanatory statement at the end solves it: plural.

*Data* is used in both singular as well as plural sense, per context.

It is better to make the fact clearer by saying '(many) elements of data' rather than just data.

*Amount* is inappropriate here. "A large amount of data ": collective, one quantity, singular.

"Large amounts of data": collective, many quantities (each a collection), plural.

"Several elements of data": individual, many items, plural.