# "Data shows" Vs "Data show"

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “data” considered singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/is-data-considered-singular-or-plural)

I was reading a book in which the author has used the sentence as follows:

> ***Data show*** that unemployment in America is in smaller states where farming is 
>   the main occupation.

But when I am searching [in the internet](http://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/revised-data-shows-japan-heading-081941068.html) it reveals that **Data shows** is used more frequently.

Can anyone explain the correct usage?

Comment: It depends on whether you're addressing stickler professors and pedantic scholars or not, apparently.

Comment: This has been talked to death, and not just here. The bottom line is whichever you choose, you will annoy half your readers. My answer is to avoid the question: talk about *the facts* or *the numbers*, or rewrite: *What is clear in the data is X*, or *What is shown by the data is X*.