# Data don't lie or Data doesn't lie?

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

Which form is more appropriate and why?

> Data don't lie

or

> Data doesn't lie

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  Your question already has an answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/is-the-word-data-now-considered-singular-if-so-what-about-datum)

Comment: Neither is incorrect (and 'The data doesn't lie' is my usual choice). But some institutions prefer the older treatment, using 'data' as a count usage, when as it is plural in form it requires plural agreement. But notice that 'news' is also plural in form but is never given plural agreement, and 'data' is heading this way.

Comment: Are you a Star Trek fan?  An AAVE speaker?